# login page works without correct credentials in java jsp servlet with database

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets

Hello i am new to stackoverflow.Recently i developed a project with login,Registration page using java servlets and database.Yesterday my code runs with correct only(if i put wrong credentials,it shows"Data not found ,click on register")..Today i run the same code,with putting wrong credentials,it automatically login without validating.Please resolve my issues.Hereby i attached my code

**MyShopDAOimplcode**

```
package login.sg.registration;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class ShopDAOimpl implements ShopDAO {

    static Connection con;
    static PreparedStatement ps;
    
    @Override
    public int insertShopName(Shop s) {
        
        int status=0;
        try {
            con=MyConnectionProvider.getCon();
            ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into shop123  (id,shopName,password,ownerName,address) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, s.getId());
            ps.setString(2, s.getShopname());
            ps.setString(3, s.getPassword());
            ps.setString(4, s.getName());
            ps.setString(5, s.getAddress());
            //System.out.println("new comment" + s.getShopname());
            status=ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("insert ps  " + ps);
            con.close();
            
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return status;
    }

    @Override
    public Shop getShop(String Shopname, String pass) {
        
        Shop s= new Shop();
        try {
            con=MyConnectionProvider.getCon();  
            //System.out.println("after connection");
            ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from  shop123 where shopname=? and password=?");
            ps.setString(1, Shopname);
            ps.setString(2, pass);
            //System.out.println(ps);
            System.out.println(Shopname);
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                s.setShopname(rs.getString(1));
                s.setPassword(rs.getString(2));
                s.setName(rs.getString(3));
            }
            }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    return s;
        
    }

    }
```

**my LoginRegister code**

```
package login.sg.registration;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



@WebServlet("/LoginRegister")
public class LoginRegister extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       


    public LoginRegister() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ShopDAO S= new ShopDAOimpl();
        String submitType=request.getParameter("submit");

        if(submitType.equals("login")){
            String shopName=request.getParameter("name");
               // System.out.println(shopName);
                String password=request.getParameter("password1");

                Shop s=S.getShop(shopName, password);
                System.out.println(s.getShopname()+s.getPassword());
            request.setAttribute("message", s.getName());
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Home.jsp").forward(request, response);
            
        }else if(submitType.equals("register")) {
            //System.out.println("register now function starts");
            Shop s = new Shop();
            s.setShopname(request.getParameter("shopname"));
            //System.out.println("test comment " +request.getParameter("shopname"));
            s.setPassword(request.getParameter("password1"));
            s.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
            s.setAddress(request.getParameter("address"));
            s.setId(request.getParameter("id"));
            request.getParameter ("password1");
            S.insertShopName(s);
            request.setAttribute("successMessage","Registration Sucessfull!!!...login using your credentials");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);   
            
            
        }else {
            request.setAttribute("message","Data Not Found,click on Register !!!");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);       
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: None of your code validates any input. All it does is an if/elseif/else on `submitType`.

Comment: i added my code which validates

Comment: Your code still does not validate anything usefully. If the credentials are wrong, your query returns an empty ResultSet, in which case you still do not react to that and return a `new Shop();`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
Shop s = S.getShop(shopName, password);
System.out.println(s.getShopname() + s.getPassword());

if (null != s.getName()) {
    request.setAttribute("message", s.getName());
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Home.jsp").forward(request, response);
} else {
    request.setAttribute("message", "Data Not Found,click on Register !!!");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```